# Burning an array of paths using genisoimage

Tags: linux, bash

I have an array of files (some have spaces).  I use genisoimage to create an iso file from these files, but the spaces mess it up.

Here's an example:

```
#This is my array of files.  Note: "2 a" is a filename with a space in it.
files=(1 "2 a" 3)

#Here I try to create an iso file with the files in the array..fail
echo "${files[@]}"|xargs genisoimage -o "test.iso"
```

I get this output:

```
genisoimage: No such file or directory. Invalid node - '2'.
```

If I just look at the output of `echo "${files[@]}`, I see that the output of files is not properly quoting the filenames (thus `2 a` becomes `2`)

Is there a way to output an array of files that will be properly escaped for use by xargs?  I'd prefer a way to just output the element separator as a null character so I can use the `-0` option in xargs.

Comment: Does `genisoimage` concat multiple files to one?

Comment: @kev:  genisoimage creates a single file from several input files.  Unfortunately, I did not see an "append" feature where I could just call genisoimage once for each file and end up with a single iso containing all files.